# What are the best possible ways to move replicate data from CloudSQL into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

What are the best possible ways to move replicate data from CloudSQL into BigQuery?

Comment: Do you want to move a specific tables from cloudsql ? or whole DB?

Comment: Can you precise the Cloud SQL engine that you use?

Comment: Want to move the whole DB to big query

Comment: I am not sure what your are asking like in I use Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, and Compute Engine

Comment: Not an answer per se, but have you looked at federated queries? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries

Comment: Yep been looking st SQL federated queries which takes lot of time for big  db and checking at fusion as well but its not that cost effective